# Failing to convert json with number property names to c# object

Tags: c#, json

I have a json collection that uses numbers as property names. I am using Newtonsoft JsonConvert to try and deserialize to a c# object but it fails. Is this even possible?

```
{
    "0":{"_bnd":{"_path":"Style","_parts":["Style"],"_key":"Style"}},
    "1":{"_bnd":{"_path":"AcctPerfAsOfDate","_parts":"AcctPerfAsOfDate"],"_key":"AcctPerfAsOfDate"}},"length":2,"_updating":0,"collectionChanged":{"_handlers":[{}]}
}
```

Comment: it's not a valid JSON. try it here http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: It's possible.  You need to define all the fields in all the C# classes explicitly so that deserializing can match up the JSON field ids with field names in C#.  This is where YOU get to do some work to learn about how that works.

Comment: "it fails" is not the *greatest* bug report to ever cross my field of vision. Perhaps you could elaborate more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{
    "0":{"_bnd":{"_path":"Style","_parts":["Style"],"_key":"Style"}},
    "1":{"_bnd":{"_path":"AcctPerfAsOfDate","_parts":"AcctPerfAsOfDate"],"_key":"AcctPerfAsOfDate"}},"length":2,"_updating":0,"collectionChanged":{"_handlers":[{}]}
                                                           Remove this ^
}
```

Remove the ] to get a valid JSON.

UPDATE:

This is the class structure for your JSON:

```
  public class Bnd
{
    public string _path { get; set; }
    public List<string> _parts { get; set; }
    public string _key { get; set; }
}

public class __invalid_type__0
{
    public Bnd _bnd { get; set; }
}

public class Bnd2
{
    public string _path { get; set; }
    public string _parts { get; set; }
    public string _key { get; set; }
}

public class __invalid_type__1
{
    public Bnd2 _bnd { get; set; }
}

public class Handler
{
}

public class CollectionChanged
{
    public List<Handler> _handlers { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public __invalid_type__0 __invalid_name__0 { get; set; }
    public __invalid_type__1 __invalid_name__1 { get; set; }
    public int length { get; set; }
    public int _updating { get; set; }
    public CollectionChanged collectionChanged { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It's more likely to add a `[` to match the previous item. This is why we don't answer vague questions...

Comment: He has asked, why the json throws an exception. I think my answer is a possible solution. If he needs to add a "[", I think he adds it. But I can understand your suggestion. I'm relative new with SO and I have to learn. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

The second item in the collection is ambiguous. Not sure if length, _updating and collectionChanged fields belong to second item or to the collection. 
I removed it to create the example, but you can easily change the anonymous object to reflect your needs.

```
  void Main()
{
    JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(U.InputText(), new Dictionary<int, object> { })
    .ToDictionary(a=>a.Key,a=> ((JObject) a.Value).ToAnonymous(new { _bnd = new {_path=""}})).Dump();   
}

public static class ext
{
    public static T ToAnonymous<T>(this JObject source, T obj) => (T)source.ToObject(obj.GetType());
}
```